# Which user or service account was used to delete Stackdriver logs?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to keep as many logs for as long as possible in StackDriver tool. I understand that the logs can be created, deleted and read (using client libraries or gcloud CLI).

"Audit logs" are not a concern in my case as they can not be deleted but what about other logs?

E.g : ***syslog*** from a Compute Instance VM or container.

Is there a way to know which User account or Service account was used to delete logs from Stackdriver? Deletion in StackDriver get logged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log retention periods in Stackdriver Logging is documented in https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods

As of August 2019:

- Admin activity, AXT, and system event logs are retained for 400 days
- Data access audit logs and all other logs are retained for default of 30 days

In Stackdriver, individual log entries are grouped in a "Log", which are named with LogName. Logs can be deleted using the [DeleteLog API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rpc/google.logging.v2#google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2.DeleteLog) or using the equivalent [gcloud logging logs delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/delete) CLI command.

To check who deleted the log, you can check the admin activity audit logs with a filter like:

```
resource.type=logging_log AND 
logName:cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity AND 
protoPayload.methodName=google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2.DeleteLog
```

The `protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail` field will contain the user account or service account used to call the API.